# How to configure simulink model using *.m configuration scripts?

Tags: configuration, scripting, simulink

I have many Simulink model files and three `*.m` configuration scripts. When I run the scripts, it doesn't change the Simulink model setting. How can I run the scripts from command line and save the setting as default?

To clarify my question, the *.m files contain all the required configuration settings for Simulink models. For example: model = Simulink.ConfigSet; model.switchTarget('grt.tlc'); Running a script that contains these commands is supposed to set the System target file to 'grt.tlc'. I initially set the system target file to 'ert.tlc' and run the scripts. However, I don't see any change on the configuration setting after running the scripts. I'm looking for the steps I need to follow to perform this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, but I think we need more information. Can you expand it, add more details and example?

Comment: Your requirements still aren't clear.  It is possible from m-code to run a simulation (and/or generate code) by **overriding** the parameters set in the model (but without saving those changes, so that next time you manually open the model you'll see the settings originally saved with the model).  It is also possible from m-code to make permanent changes to the model (so that next time you manually open it you see the changes).  You may be doing the first of these, but expecting to see the second.  Which do you want?  BTW, the info you put in your comment should have been added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, I have figured it out. I opened a model explorer and imported the configuration script to the Simulink model. Then, activating the configuration and saving the model will permanently change the setting. To use the same configuration to multiple model, change the configuration into 'Active Configuration Reference', which will put the reference under the Base Workspace and can be referenced from any Simulik model and activated.

Helpful Simulink documentations for [adding](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/setting-up-configuration-sets.html) and [referencing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/referencing-configuration-sets.html) configurations.